# Hyperledger Fabric enroll & register admin not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, user-enrollment

I'm trying to enroll & register an admin to perform peer operations.
This is the bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="$1"
pass="$2"
org="$3"
type="$4"
tlscerts="/chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/msp/tlscacerts/ca-root-7054.pem"

fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@ca-root:7054

fabric-ca-client register --id.name ${user} --id.secret ${pass} --id.type ${type} --id.affiliation ${org} --id.attrs 'hf.Revoker=true,admin=true:ecert' -u http://ca-root:7054 --tls.certfiles ${tlscerts}

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/${org}/users/${user}@${org}/
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://${user}:${pass}@ca-root:7054 --id.affiliation ${org} --tls.certfiles ${tlscerts} 

mv /chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/${org}/users/${user}@${org}/msp/signcerts/cert.pem /chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/${org}/users/${user}@${org}/msp/signcerts/${user}@${org}-cert.pem
mkdir /chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/${org}/users/${user}@${org}/msp/admincerts/
cp /chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/${org}/users/${user}@${org}/msp/signcerts/* /chainset/hyperledger-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/${org}/users/${user}@${org}/msp/admincerts/
```

When I try to create a new channel I get this error:

```
Description: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'newchannelf', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

This is my configtx.yml configuration. I don't know if it is a problem with the policies in this configuration file or if I'm not registering & enrolling the user correctly.

```
Organizations:
  - &orderer
    Name: orderer
    ID: orderer
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('orderer.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('orderer.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('orderer.admin')"

  - &org1
    Name: org1
    ID: org1
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org1.admin', 'org1.peer', 'org1.client', 'org1.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org1.admin', 'org1.peer', 'org1.client', 'org1.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org1.admin')"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0-org1-service
        Port: 7051

  - &org2
    Name: org2
    ID: org2
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org2.admin', 'org2.peer', 'org2.client', 'org2.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org2.admin', 'org2.peer', 'org2.client', 'org2.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org2.admin')"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0-org2-service
        Port: 7051

Capabilities:
  Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    V1_4_3: true

  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V1_4_2: true

  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V1_4_2: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:
    - *orderer
    - *org1
    - *org2

  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

  OrdererType: etcdraft
  EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
      - Host: orderer0-service
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer0.default.svc.cluster.local/tls/server.crt
        ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer0.default.svc.cluster.local/tls/server.crt
      - Host: orderer1-service
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer1.default.svc.cluster.local/tls/server.crt
        ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer1.default.svc.cluster.local/tls/server.crt
      - Host: orderer2-service
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer2.default.svc.cluster.local/tls/server.crt
        ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/default.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer2.default.svc.cluster.local/tls/server.crt
  Addresses:
    - orderer0-service:7050
    - orderer1-service:7050
    - orderer2-service:7050

  BatchTimeout: 1s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

  Kafka:
    Brokers:
      - 127.0.0.1:9092

  Organizations:
    - *orderer

  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults

  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Admins"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:

  OrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Capabilities:
      <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *orderer
      Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - <<: *orderer
    Consortiums:
      MAIN:
        Organizations:
          - *org1
          - *org2

  MainChannel:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Consortium: MAIN
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *org1
        - *org2
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: What is the environment that you using while submitting the `peer channel create` command. I am assuming you are not setting the environment to the above generated identity. Let's say that you are using `cli` container, then please check the environment variables for that container.

Comment: Im using the MainChannel profile: #!/bin/bash
channelID="$1"
cfgPath="$2"
cd ${cfgPath}
configtxgen -profile MainChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channels/${channelID}.tx -channelID ${channelID} -configPath ./

Comment: Now, after getting the `.tx` file for the channel genesis, what is your `peer create channel` command? Wherever you are running these commands, please check the following environment variables: `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` , `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH`, `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS` and `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE`.

Comment: I then use golang to execute the channel creation: 
err := c.CreateChannel(org, channelID)
In my config.yaml file:
organizations:
  org1:
    mspid: org1
    cryptopath: peerOrganizations/org1/users/admin2@org1/msp
    peers:
      - peer0-org1-service
      - peer1-org1-service

Comment: The reason is because when you are registering and enrolling `admin2` identity, you are just updating the local MSP. The system channel configuration has some different admin credentials. The given admin credentials are never mounted to the system channel. Are you doing the register/enroll task after the all nodes are up? In that case it won't work. You must first update the MSPs before creating the system channel genesis block.

Comment: Yes, all nodes are up & running. Could you please go into more detail on how to " The given admin credentials are never mounted to the system channel." Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is happening:

You created a `system channel` (which is the `orderer genesis` block) by creating the `MAIN` consortium. Now the system channel was created with the `peer` organization MSPs at that moment. Followed by this, after the network was up, you went into `org1/users` and created an admin identity. You update local MSP of peer but the already existing `system channel` was never updated.

Possible solutions:

1. Update the admin credentials within `org1/users` before the network is set up.
2. Update the system channel configuration with the `admin2` credentials post deployment by creating a `channel update` transaction.
3. Enable NodeOUs so that any admin identity generated dynamically post the network deployment can perform `admin` related transactions.

Comment: I think the easiest action is enabling NodeOUs. This should be configured in the config.yaml? Thank you

Comment: How would the solution #2 work? Channel update transactions include new admin users?

Comment: Refer documentation as to how to update channel configuration. That would help you to analyse what a decoded system channel configuration block looks like in the JSON format. There you can also see the certificate present for the "admincerts" inside the particular organization's definition. You must change that certificate to treat the new certificate as the admin identity.

Comment: WRT NodeOUs, yes you must add config.yaml file to every MSP before the network is being set up so that while mounting the MSP onto the node (and hence system channel) the NodeOUs are enabled. Again you can see these OUs in system channel configuration block.